# Pandas dataframe groupby id and interpolate values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, interpolation

I have a dataframe with decade wise values for many ids, like so:

```
id year value
1  2020  0.09
1  2030  0.1
1  2040  0.11
2  2020  0.09
2  2030  0.1
2  2040  0.11
```

I want to interpolate (maybe linearly) to get year wise values for each of the ids. How can I do that?

What if I want month wise values (year column itself should include month also)? How to do that?

Comment: So what would be the value for 2025? The average of `0.09` and `0.1`?

Comment: @jorijnsmit yes, if we are linearly interpolating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) and [`Resampler.interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.interpolate.html):

```
#for DatetimeIndex
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['year'], format='%Y').rename('datetimes')

df = (df.groupby('id')['value']
        .apply(lambda x: x.resample('MS').interpolate())
        .reset_index())
print (df)
     id  datetimes     value
0     1 2020-01-01  0.090000
1     1 2020-02-01  0.090083
2     1 2020-03-01  0.090167
3     1 2020-04-01  0.090250
4     1 2020-05-01  0.090333
..   ..        ...       ...
477   2 2039-09-01  0.109667
478   2 2039-10-01  0.109750
479   2 2039-11-01  0.109833
480   2 2039-12-01  0.109917
481   2 2040-01-01  0.110000

[482 rows x 3 columns]
```